# sort a hash by a property of the value

Tags: ruby

I have a hash that has "Song" objects as values. These song objects have a property 'updated_at' that I want to sort them by. I tried something like:

```
@data.values.updated_at.sort
```

but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Figured it out myself. I had to convert it to an array before sorting

Answer (score 1):

You want to check the [documentation of `Enumerable#sort_by`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by)

e.g.

```
[{name: 'ryan', number: 3},
 {name: 'john', number: 1},
 {name: 'june', number: 2}].sort_by{|item| item[:number]}
```

Hopefully that is enough to get you going.

Comment: I don't understand how guiding someone to the answer rather than giving someone the answer gets negative votes.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply:

```
@data.values.sort_by(&:updated_at)
```

For example:

```
class A
  attr_reader :updated_at
  def initialize(updated_at)
    @updated_at = updated_at
  end
end

@data = { "Bob"=>A.new(3), "Trixi"=>A.new(1), "Bubba"=>A.new(2) }
  #=> {"Bob"=>#<A:0x007ffa191935a0 @updated_at=3>,
  #    "Trixi"=>#<A:0x007ffa19193550 @updated_at=1>, 
  #    "Bubba"=>#<A:0x007ffa19193528 @updated_at=2>} 

@data.values.sort_by(&:updated_at)
  #=> [#<A:0x007ffa19193550 @updated_at=1>,
  #    #<A:0x007ffa19193528 @updated_at=2>,
  #    #<A:0x007ffa191935a0 @updated_at=3>]
```